# How to get multiple input value on html <fieldset> to javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Everybody. I hope all of you, have a great day today.
We want to ask you about, how to get data / value from multiple  and store them to javascript for another process (save to database). I'm very happy, and thanks a lot for your response, attention, and solution. Sorry, if this is a newbie question.

[Click here for pastebin codelink](http://pastebin.com/BcDzNJTv)

Answer (score 0):

you have to serialize your form data using

```
$(#yourformid).submit(function(){
 var values=$this.serialize;
 insertData(values);
 return false;
 }
```

then use a function to post your data using ajax.

```
function insertData(values)
    {
        var array=[];
        $.ajax({
        url: 'xyz.php',
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:'text',
        success: function(str)
        {
        array.push(values);
        console.log(array);
        $("#results").html(str);//any success function. include this in your code for output.
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
        });     
    }
```

Comment: use <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button> instead of the function in your code.

Comment: thanks alot for your suggestion. I has made the way to get it correctly.